# Howto signin a default IdentityUser at startup using blazor with .Net8

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

How can automatically login with a defaultuser from identityuser database without using login page UI at startup?

I saw different approaches with AuthenticationHandlers for debugging purposes but this solution is static for whole app lifetime and did not let user change.

I am using Blazor Server not WASM.

Comment: Did you try to inject `SignInManager` and `UserManager` services into your component or service? and in the `OnInitializedAsync` method of your component or service, check if the default user exists in the database.

Comment: Yes i tried to use SignInManager in OnInitializeAsync method of my Login page but i doesnt work.

Comment: Hi @datenwerk, what you have done so far? Do you read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) about how to secure in blazor server app?